# MacPorts: How do I make py32-scipy not depend on gcc48?

Tags: macports, gcc

MacPorts has many unnecessary dependencies. I need to disable the dependency of `py32-scipy` on `gcc48` because `gcc48` won't build on my system for some reason. I get this error:

(much information removed)

```
:info:build echo "#define LOCALEDIR \"/opt/local/share/gcc-4.8/locale\"" > localedir.new
:info:build clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
:info:build /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc48/gcc48/work/gcc-4.8.1/libcpp/../move-if-change localedir.new localedir.h
:info:build ranlib: unrecognized option `-q'
:info:build ranlib: Try `ranlib --help' for more information.
:info:build ar: internal ranlib command failed
:info:build /usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -pipe -Os -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -o fixincl fixincl.o fixtests.o fixfixes.o server.o procopen.o fixlib.o fixopts.o ../libiberty/libiberty.a
```

Sure, it would be better to fix this, but I'd really just rather get py32-scipy installed. I've got a working gcc; I don't need `gcc48`.

Comment: They are not unnecessary dependencies, they have been found to be needed after much debugging of issues. Which gcc do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately py32-scipy does depend on gcc4.8 as it depends on some c libraries which is a set of numerical routines that are optimised to run on your machine and so I think need to be compiled there.

Normally Macports does not compile but downloads precompiled binaries so you should not need to compile gcc48. So check the vlue of buildfromsource in /opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf it should be ifneeded. It does do this for me on OSX 10.8 got gcc4.8.

Also check you have the latest ports (gcc48 and the std C++ libraries have caused much comment on the macports mailing lists so will have changed) by running `sudo port selfupdate`

You can give py32-scipy a variant to chnage the version of gcc used but that will still need a macports gcc compiler as Xcode 4 does not come with gcc but a program that looks like gcc but uses clang.

Comment: Fascinating. My /opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf  has `#buildfromsource`. I have now un-commented it.

Comment: Then you should have been getting builds from macports as the commented out version show what is the default